# wait for http request to complete in protractor

Tags: protractor, jasmine2.0

I am trying to wait for spinner to disappear and then for my steps to execute but nothing is working for me.

> browser.wait(function () {
>
> return this.spinner.isDisplayed().then(function (result) {
>
> return !result;});}, 20000);

and i even tried with

> browser.wait(function () {
>
> return !browser.isElementPresent(this.spinner);}, 20000);

even with below method

> browser.sleep(1000);
>
> this.spinner.isPresent().then(function (result) {
>
> if (result === true) {
>
> var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
>
> browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(this.spinner), 10000);}});

then only thing that works is

> browse.sleep(10000);

i don't want to use sleep in my code. can anyone help me with how to wait for complete http request to complete and then process with testing

Comment: can you provide what is this.spinner?

Comment: Also when you say it fails, what does that mean? Do you get any error?

Comment: this.spinner is xpath of the spinner, "element(by.xpath('//div[contains(@class="spinner")]'))" and the problem is here if the the spinner is not displayed before time passes out then we get error message message saying the no element found.

Answer (score 2):

you should consider using Expected Conditions since they return true/false based on current conditions

http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.invisibilityOf

so your test case would become:

```
browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(this.spinner),20000).then(function(){
    ...continue test, spinner gone
});
```

UPDATE

in order to use `done`, you would generally pass this cb into your `it()` function. This means your test could look like

```
describe("example describe",function(){
  it("should be an example only", function(done){
    request.get("www.google.com",function(res){
      //done with async request, now call done
      done();
    })
  })
});
```

Since your entire code isn't posted up here, you should have something similar to:

```
it("should wait for spinner to go bye-bye",function(done){
  browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(this.spinner),20000).then(function(){
    done()
  });
});
```

Comment: in your callback (ie `.then`) are you calling `done()` to flag asynchronous completion?

Comment: no. i am unaware of done() can u help me out will try that too.

Comment: see UPDATE for more info